# ¿Cómo puedo sumar datos con Firestore y JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy intentando sumar datos de firestore en firebase desde una base de datos que creé. El caso es que cada dato se guarda individualmente; aquí está el código que guarda el valor cada vez que el usuario presiona un botón:

nota:(la coleccion se llama "dinero)
nota:(lo que intento sumar es "valores")

```
sumar.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('has dado click')
    
    
    firebase.firestore().collection('dinero').add({
      valor: 2000,
      uid: user.uid,
    })
    .then(res => {console.log('guardado')})
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
    
    })
```

Esto pasa cuando ejecuto un console.log:
[image: console.log]

Así se ve la base de datos desde Cloud Firestore:
[image: ibase de datos]

Y así cuando en el HTML ejecutando el `inner.html`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve el código que devuelve los valores a la consola y a el HTML:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('dinero').orderBy('uid')
.onSnapshot(query => {
    query.forEach(doc => {          
      if(user.uid === doc.data().uid){
        var completado = doc.data().valor

      dinerocontainer.innerHTML += `
      <a id="intentosuma">${completado}</a>
      `
      console.log(completado)
      }


    })
  })
```

Quiero que se sumen esos 4 dos mil, pero no he encontrado la manera de programarlo.

Asimismo cuando se introduzcan más datos quiero que se sumen todos los datos.

En el INNER.HTML le agregue el id de "intentosuma" y como se ve hay 4 datos, pues esto lo que hace es que genere 4 div de html:

```
<div id="intentosuma">2000</div>
<div id="intentosuma">2000</div>
<div id="intentosuma">2000</div>
<div id="intentosuma">2000</div>
```

Todos tienen el mismo id e intenté sumarlos pero tampoco lo conseguí, tal vez porque todos tienen el mismo id; tal vez hay una manera de que al crear un nuevo dato se genere un # de id diferente. Además, no sé si este método sea efectivo ya que al parecer lo reconoce como texto el "2000" y no como número.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Javascript tomará los valores como cadena por defecto, por tanto para hacer operaciones aritméticas con ellos tendrás que convertirlos a entero con `parseInt()` o a valores de punto flotante con `parseFloat()`. Por otro lado, no puedes dar el mismo ID a varios elementos. El ID debe ser único, si no, cuando quieras alcanzar ese elemento por su ID, ¿cuál de ellos se va a seleccionar? Ten en cuenta también que puedes alcanzar varios elementos al mismo tiempo si fuera necesario, usando su `class`, el tipo de elemento, el contenedor donde está, etc.